# Calculate sum in tier pricing. SQL Server. Tier pricing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with my sum query in SQL Server.

I have a tier price table set up like. The name of the table is called TierPricing.

```
CID RangeID MinValue    MaxValue    Price   Class
1   1        1          5           1.50    1
2   2        6          10          1.25    1
3   3        11         999999999   1.00    1
```

.

I have a query of

```
DECLARE @QuantityEntered int
DECLARE @ClassEntered int

SET @QuantityEntered = 10;
SET @ClassEntered = 1

SELECT IIf(@QuantityEntered>=TierPricing.MaxValue,TierPricing.MaxValue*TierPricing.Price,(@QuantityEntered-(TierPricing.MinValue-1))*TierPricing.Price)) AS RangePrice
FROM 
  TierPricing
WHERE 
  (((TierPricing.MinValue)<=@QuantityEntered) AND ((TierPricing.Class)=@ClassEntered));
```

The problem arises when I use the value of 10 for @QuantityEntered. Instead of returning 13.75 it returns 20.00 and I cant figure out why. From the table from value 9 to 10 should increase by 1.25 from 12.50 to 13.75.

Further Explanation.

```
 @QuantityEntered =  1 returns  1.50   because 1 falls in between 1 and 5 and 1.50 is added from price field for a total of 1.50
    @QuantityEntered =  2 returns  3.00   because 2 falls in between 1 and 5 and 1.50 is added from price field for total of 3.00
    @QuantityEntered =  3 returns  4.50   because 3 falls in between 1 and 5 and 1.50 is from price field added for total of 4.50
    @QuantityEntered =  4 returns  6.00   because 4 falls in between 1 and 5 and 1.50 is from price field added for total of 6.00
    @QuantityEntered =  5 returns  7.50   because 5 falls in between 1 and 5 and 1.50 is from price field added for total of 7.50
    @QuantityEntered =  6 returns  8.75   because 6 falls in between 6 and 10 and 1.25 is from price field added for total of 8.75
    @QuantityEntered =  7 returns  10.00  because 7 falls in between 6 and 10 and 1.25 is from price field added for total of 10.00
    @QuantityEntered =  8 returns  11.25  because 8 falls in between 6 and 10 and 1.25 is from price field added for total of 11.25
    @QuantityEntered =  9 returns  12.50  because 9 falls in between 6 and 10 and 1.25 is from price field added for total of 12.50
    @QuantityEntered =  10 Should return 13.75 but returns 20.00
```

What I am doing wrong with my query?

Comment: Why "@QuantityEntered =  10 Should return 13.75", not just 12.50 (1.25 x 10)?

Comment: @Anton. Because items 1 through 5 are billed at 1.50 and items 6-10 are billed at 1.25.

Comment: Can you add one more column into TierPricing, like TotalPriceAdjustment? So e.g. all items from 6 to 10 have 7.50, all items from 11 to 999999 have 13.75. Then the query will be simple with formula: TotalPriceAdjustment + (Value - MinValue + 1) x Price

Comment: Uh... All you need to do is change `IIf(@QuantityEntered>=` to `IIf(@QuantityEntered>`

Comment: Actually, never mind. That just fixes the 10 issue. The actual fix is just changing `TierPricing.MaxValue*TierPricing.Price` to `(TierPricing.MaxValue - TierPricing.MinValue + 1)*TierPricing.Price`

Comment: @ZLK.  This works! Thanks! How can I mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to solve this problem myself when I found your question. I figured out a set based way to get the correct result, but you have to change your Min and Max values to start from 0 and start from the lower tier's end. So the tiers are now 0-5, 5-10, and 10 - 999999999. Here is a recreation of your problem:

```
create table #TierPricing
(
     CID int
    ,RangeId int
    ,MinValue int
    ,MaxValue int
    ,Price money
    ,Class int
)

insert into #TierPricing(CID, RangeId, MinValue, MaxValue, Price, Class) values (1,1,0,5,1.50,1)
insert into #TierPricing(CID, RangeId, MinValue, MaxValue, Price, Class) values (2,2,5,10,1.25,1)
insert into #TierPricing(CID, RangeId, MinValue, MaxValue, Price, Class) values (3,3,10,999999999,1.00,1)

DECLARE @QuantityEntered int
DECLARE @ClassEntered int

SET @QuantityEntered = 10;
SET @ClassEntered = 1

;with t as (
select
    #TierPricing.*
    ,case
        when @QuantityEntered > MaxValue then MaxValue - MinValue --The @QuantityEntered fills up the entire tier
        when @QuantityEntered > MinValue then @QuantityEntered - MinValue --The @QuantityEntered partillay fills the tier
        else 0
        end as TierQuantity 
from #TierPricing   
)
select
    sum(TierQuantity * Price) as RangePrice
from t

drop table #TierPricing
```

This will return 13.75 when `@QuantityEntered` is set to 10.